# How clone div jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, label

I need to clone some parts of a HTML page but I've got something wrong.

```
<div id="question_answer">
    <label for="label_questions">Questions</label>
    <input type"text" name="questions_name">
    <div id="answer">
        <label for="label_answer">Answer</label>
        <input type="text" name="answers_name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Suppose there is a number of questions that we know X (example `x=4`) my code is:

```
var div_questions_answer = $('#question_answer');
var div_answer = $('#answer');

for (var i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    var label = $('label[for^="label_questions"]').clone();
    div_answer.append(label);
}
div_questions_answer.append(div_answer);
```

I can't see the four label but I can see only one!Anyone can help me?

Comment: Why do you append `div_answer` for second time, its already there?

Comment: I am not sure about the problem. The code looks fine. Try using `$('label[for^="label_questions"]').first().clone()`. If not you'll end up with `1+ 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + X` labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$QuestionAns = $('#question_answer').clone();
```

Comment: Needs explanation and expanding.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do this?

```
var div_answer = $("#answer");
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $('#question_answer > label[for^="label_questions"]').clone().appendTo("#answer");
}
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/7b8bfgjk/12/)**

Comment: That will only get the content of the element. *ie* simple text.

Answer (score 0):

@RejithRKrishnan's comment was reasonable in regard to there must be clone of a single label element. But `$('label[for^="label_questions"]')` selector gets multiple elements if they are presented in markup (after at leat first loop iteration).
Use the following solution to attach a single clone to the `div_answer` element:

```
var div_questions_answer = $('#question_answer');
var div_answer = $('#answer');
var label = $('label[for^="label_questions"]:first').clone();

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    label.clone().appendTo(div_answer);
}
div_questions_answer.append(div_answer);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bg9vbge9/